# Broken slider loading images vertically

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm using a thumbnail slider on my site and it loads the images vertically for a split second before arranging them properly.

There are no errors in the console so im unsure how to approach this.

Any tips are greatly appreciated.

[image]http://breakingcapital.com/

Answer (score 0):

Nice site. I think the best answer will be to add a class with `display: none` to your images and remove it once the plugin has finished. I assume the vertical issue is to do with the way your markup displays the images, before the javascript kicks in.

Another solution which is not ideal will be to move the slider logic into the `<head></head>` as opposed to below the body, but that will slow down the initial load-up of your site.